# Subdomains in Joomla 1.5

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, joomla1.5

How do I set up a subdomain in Joomla 1.5?  I have a classifieds component and want to show each category URL as its own subdomain URL.  For example, if I select the electronics category then it will show `electronics.mysite.com`.

I want it to be just like http://www.nintendolife.com

Answer (score 0):

idea 1: Wait for an SEO extension to add it as a feature, like [Artio](http://www.artio.net/support-forums/joomsef/how-to-implement-subdomains-with-joomsef)

idea2: You need to [wildcard your subdomains](http://forums.knownhost.com/showthread.php?p=12306) in DNS/Apache, then add a full url link to your top level nav in the Joomla menu manager as a link: http://electronics.mysite.com/whatever-it-points-to

[You could also add .htaccess redirects but it won't retain the full URL without the wildcard passthrough above and function normally on subpages]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how can we do using htaccess redirect method. could you give me some steps so i can implement in joomla site till [Artio](http://www.artio.net/) add this feature